# How to set from code the query range in Query object?

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

I created a query in the AOT (and open it with a View).

I want to set the queryRange in my Query object from code .
In my init method I used this code :

```
Query q = new Query();
QueryRun qr;
QueryBuildDataSource qbds;

qbds = q.addDataSource(tableNum(MyTable));
qbds.addRange(fieldNum(MyTable, MyField)).value(SysQuery::valueUnlimited() ) ;
qr = new QueryRun (q) ;
```

But when I launch a View I don't see this query, the promt only shows the query with index-field.
It's possible to set the range from code ?

Comment: You miss understand query is different from jquery

Comment: Thanks JqueryKing for your comment, then I can't to open query with the precompiled  parameters range and choose the criteria?

I know to set the range from Range node, but I would like to set the promt.
greetings!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of creating new query, use objects query:

```
public void init()
{
    super();
    query.dataSourceNo(1).addRange(fieldNum(MyTable, MyField)).value(SysQuery::valueUnlimited());
}
```